# Cocoa Versions Browser: full screen

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, versions, autosave

I have a problem in my document-based application, when it is in a Version Browsing mode.

It seems that although the version browsing UI fills the entire primary screen, the secondary screen is not darkened to black (as in version browser of other apps like TextEdit and Pages), and the "Hot Corners" are enabled (unlike TextEdit's and Pages' which disable the "hot corners" in version browsing mode).

Any idea why isn't the Version Browser in my app does not behaves like Pages' Version Browser
Should I do anything explicitly to disable the hot corners and to darken the secondary screen in Version Browser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
My application behaves the same as Pages and TextEdit when it is not run from Xcode.

Anyway, if anybody is interested in how to disable "hot corners" and other operations to move between processes, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941449/disabling-mission-control-spaces-dashboard-and-any-other-external-process) and it links to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html).